# How to upload payment picture by orders, 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, view

I can't filter to upload pictures.
I want to upload pictures by :

> orders= Order.objects.filter(id=orid, id_profil=id_profil)

get error :

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

view.py

```
def Detail(request, orid=None):
data = cartData(request)
cartItems       = data['cartItems']
id_profil       = request.user.profile 
orders          = Order.objects.filter(id=orid, id_profil=id_profil)
OrderItems      = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=orid)
pengirimans     = Pengiriman.objects.filter(order=orid)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = Uplaodpic(request.POST ,request.FILES ,instance=orders)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
else:
    form=Uplaodpic(instance=orders)
context = {'orders':orders, 'OrderItems':OrderItems, 'pengirimans':pengirimans, 'cartItems':cartItems, 'form':form}
return render(request, 'store/detail.html' ,context)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Order, Profile
class Uplaodpic(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Order
        fields=["id","bukti"]
```

detial.html

```
 <td colspan="2">
            <img src="{{ order.buktiURL }}" alt="image" class="img-thumbnail" style="max-height:100px">
          </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <form action="" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{form.as_p}}
              <input type="Submit" id="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

modes.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id_profil    = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order_data   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    selesai      = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    status       = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    id_transaksi = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True) 
    bukti        = models.ImageField(upload_to='bukti/',default="person-circle.svg",null=True, blank=True)
    ongkir       = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True) 
    total        = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    total_harga  = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    pembayaran   = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`instance` parameter here should be a single object, not QuerySet. Judging by `id` name, you should be using `get` instead of `filter` to fetch a single object or fail. So, your code could look like this (after very basic formatting to become readable):

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound

def Detail(request, orid=None):
    data = cartData(request)
    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    id_profil = request.user.profile 
    OrderItems = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=orid)
    pengirimans = Pengiriman.objects.filter(order=orid)
    
    try:
        # Note the singular
        order = Order.objects.get(id=orid, id_profil=id_profil)
    except Order.DoesNotExist:  # Not owned bu user or does not exist
        return HttpResponseNotFound()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Uplaodpic(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=order)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = Uplaodpic(instance=order)

    context = {
        'order': order,  # Note the singular, you're using "order" in template anyway
        'OrderItems': OrderItems, 
        'pengirimans': pengirimans, 
        'cartItems': cartItems, 
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'store/detail.html', context)
```

(note that it would be better to spell `Upload`, not `Uplaod`...)

Comment: Thanks you so much, it solve
I make 2 orders : 
orders = Order.objects.filter(id=orid, id_profil=id_profil)
order = Order.objects.get(id=orid, id_profil=id_profil) to instance ,

Comment: These two queries are redundant. `orders` are now QuerySet with a single value. You can use only `get` and pass `[order]` (list) instead of QuerySet, if you need a collection for some reason. You perform two db queries when only one is required.

Comment: yeah, but if I just used order by Get, my Order can't run